# How can I interface with terraform from an external APP?

Tags: terraform

I'm using a PHP APP, BoxBilling. It takes orders from final users, these orders need to be processed into actual nodes and containers.

I was planning on using `Terraform` as the provisioner for both, containers whenever there is room available in existing nodes or new nodes whenever the existing ones are full.
Terraform would interface with my provider for creating new nodes and with Vagrant for configuring containers.
Vagrant would interface with Kubernetes to provision the pods/containers.

Question is: Is there an inbound Terraform API that I can use to send orders to Terraform from the BoxBilling APP?
I've searched the documentation, examples and case studies but it's eluding me...

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You could orchestrate the provisioning of infrastructure and/or configuration of nodes using an orchestration/CI tool such as Jenkins.

Jenkins has a [Remote Access API](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/jenkins/remote+access+api) which could be called to trigger a set of steps which could include Terraform plan, apply, creation of new workspaces etc and then downstream to configuration, testing and anything else in your toolchain.

Comment: Thank you Mattec, I will try to extend BoxBilling's Logic so it can communicate with K8S and with the cloud provider API.